# find: fts_read: Permission denied through mount_nullfs

Tags: freebsd, zfs, bind-mount

I have the following set-up:

FreeBSD 10.3 with ZFS on root.  A ZFS volume hierarchy (multiple volumes nested in each other, for lack of a better name) is duplicated using `mount_nullfs` in order to make it available to multiple jails at once.

When I try to use `find` as a normal user on the nullfs-mount I get the following error.

```
find: fts_read: Permission denied
```

`find` does find some files before failing, it seems to fail when it tries to leave a `nullfs_mount`.  The output contains all files from the first volume it recurses.

This **only** happens when I run find from within the jail and as a user. It does not happen:

- As root through nullfs
- As root directly on the filesystem
- As user directly on the filesystem

Is there some option to `mount_nullfs` that i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying directory that `mount_nullfs` mounts over is not traversable to the user.  Unmount the nullfs and make sure that users are still able to traverse the directory:

```
chmod 755 /path/to/unmounted/nullfs
```

It seems that when traversing away from a filesystem using `cd ..`, the permissions of the underlying directory are used, not the permissions of the mounted filesystem.

Comment: That's a strange bug/feature of nullfs! Mounting normally completely shadows the directory that serves as a mount point.

Comment: Doesn't have to be nullfs per se, but I haven't had the time to test with other filesystems.

Comment: @jornane - can you update your answer to cover this scenario - the mountpoint is controlled by ACLs (perhaps because it's within a dir shared over samba with Windows clients) so that chmod is unavailable on it. What then?